# What to write when I cannot create stories?

Tags: planning, inspiration

I believe that I am good at expressing things specially in writing. I like to write.

I have seen on this site that people usually have stories in their mind but don't know how to write it! 
My problem is that I can describe something very well, but I don't have the imagination to "create" stories.

What are my options for writing as a hobby?

Comment: Your favorited answer is about finding inspiration for creating stories. I think the rest of us thought you were asking about what to write without creating stories. Should this question be reworded to clarify?

Answer (score 5):

Ghost writing? You can even make money from it. Editing would also be good for you I think. Also journalism, biography novels, travel stories, memoirs. For example you can create a blog and include stories of places you have visited. Just an example.

Comment: Oh and reviews. For example restaurant reviews, food reviews, food recipes.

Answer (score 4):

If you can describe things well then don't worry about not being able to create story. Every writer is different in his/her style. Once you start writing you can move into different genres of it. For you at this phase, you can do the following:

1. Travel writing
2. Content and technical writing
3. Blogs - you can write any genre of blogs
4. Fashion Blogger - if interest in fashion

These are just some options. You could pursue any of them and with time you can earn a living through this. But initially, I would suggest not to think more about money but think about how well you can describe things, places, etc.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

“Where do you get your inspiration?”

This is an often hated, and feared, Q author’s get. Their ability to generate good ideas at the drop of a pin seems unnatural and exceptional to non-writers. They appear like inspired and gifted individuals for whom muses dance.

A couple years ago I started developing a story mostly based on my life. After a few weeks of expending on the novel, all these other ideas started coming to me.

As time went by, I had more and more ideas, aand I now have a dozen notebooks full of books projects.

My point is that it seems to me that inspiration is like a muscle, the more you exercise it, the bigger it gets.

So, devote some time to try to write a story, any story, and soon you will start hearing the soft echos of divine murmurs.

Answer (score 0):

Poetry?

I write 100-word pieces of fiction and it's sometimes tricky to get "story" into so few words. It's much easier to make them into little scenes or observations or even tiny essays. I don't write poetry, but these little things sometimes feel like it.